# How to set default RDP setting?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-registry, azure, virtual-desktop

I've been using the new windows virtual desktop (WVD) service on Azure. (for those who don't know its a service by microsoft to set up a RDP enviroment very easily).

Now I'm trying to use Skype on the virtual desktop hosts, but skype can't find my microphone. I did some research and found you can put an entry(audiocapturemode:i:1) in the rdp file used, this worked but the file is auto generated. Does anyone have an idea how i can set the audiocapturemode to be automaticly enabled? Maybe a key in the registry?

The host PC's are windows 10 multiuser. I connect to the hosts using the new remote desktop app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for the solution. I found it by a comment posted on the Windows Virtual desktop tech community.

You just have to use one of the WVD commands discribed in the documentation:

Set-RdsHostPool -TenantName  -HostPoolName  -CustomRdpProperty "audiocapturemode:i:1"